# Perl one-liner to convert first character uppercase - logic understanding

Tags: regex, perl

In the following Perl command lines, trying to turn the first and second char into uppercase

```
echo pet | perl -pe 's/^(.{0})(.)/$1\U$2/'    # Ans: Pet
echo pet | perl -pe 's/^(.{1})(.)/$1\U$2/'    # Ans: pEt
```

but could not understand the syntax **(.{0})(.)** and **(.{1})(.)**

Could you clarify how it works?

However, I found that the above can be simply achieved by the following syntax:

```
echo pet | perl -pe 's/(\w)/\U$1\E/'   # Ans: Pet
echo pet | perl -pe 's/(\w)(\w)/$1\U$2/' # Ans: pEt
```

The back reference when placed between **\U** and **\E** will be converted to uppercase

Answer (score 2):

The difference between:

```
echo pet | perl -pe 's/^(.{0})(.)/$1\U$2/'    # Ans: Pet
echo pet | perl -pe 's/^(.{1})(.)/$1\U$2/'    # Ans: pEt
```

is that nothing is matched in the first capture group in the first case, whereas `p` is captured in the first group in the second case.

A shorter equivalent of the first case would be:

```
$ echo pet | perl -pe 's/^(.)/\U$1/'
Pet
```

Additionally, the following should clarify it:

```
$ echo pet | perl -pe 's/^(.{0})(.)/$1\U$2$2/'
PPet
```

(The second backreference is printed twice, and it produces 2 `P`s.)